# How to deserialize JSON with this stru in c#

Tags: json, javascriptserializer

Hi guys I'm new to this.

how would you deserialize json with this structure?

```
{
"0":{"name":"Simon"},
"1":{"name":"Les"},
"2":{"name":"Brian"}
"status_code":"1"
}
```

I already tried using 
    JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(result); 
but it doesn't work.

any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: the popular NewtonSoft.Json will probably work. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Comment: hi @mtbnunu I tried to use NewtonSoft.Json,JsonConvert.DeserializeObject();

Comment: @mtbnunu I tried your suggestion I used Newton.Json.JsonConvert().DeserializeObject(); But how can I access the Property of Object "0"? dynamic r = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData);

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, but I remember it changes special variable names to something else, probably _0, I would suggest stepping through to test your result variable. Also, if you know the structure of the json then you can deserialize it into class, making it easier to use. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Answer (score -2):

JSON.parse().

var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );

In browsers that don't, you can include the json2 library.